# How do we create a better definition (for my definition of average) which is easier to compute and gives exact values?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, definition, average, amenability

This not the same as "[Coming up with a rigorous definition for a Riemann-like sum which is easier to compute?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655102/coming-up-with-a-rigorous-definition-for-a-riemman-like-sum-which-is-easier-to-c)
". Here I'm assuming my Riemann-like sum is clear enough to understand. If not, try and answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655102/coming-up-with-a-rigorous-definition-for-a-riemman-like-sum-which-is-easier-to-c).

---

Consider $f:A\to[0,1]$ where $A\subseteq[a,b]$. I want to create a simple, easy-to-use average of $f$ that matches my intuition. However, it is hard to explain in words so I created a section, (see the title "**My Sum**"), which matches my intuition.

Before I go further, I want to explain why the Lebesgue/Khinchine Integral doesn't give what I want:

### Problems with the Lebesgue Khichnine Integral

> 1) When $s<f<0$ or $0<f<t $ with $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\lambda(A)=0$, the Lebesgue/Khinchine Integral does not give an average between the infimum and supremum of the range of  $f$. In fact, the average is undefined.
>
> Note when $\lambda(A)>0$, the average is always between the infimum and supremum of $f$'s range. I want that property to be extended to $\lambda(A)=0$.
>
> 2) The Lebesgue/Khinchine integral does not give countable points "infinitely less weight" for the average of $f$ than uncountable points.
>
> When $\lambda(A)=0$, uncountable points are treated the exact same as countable points. However, uncountably many points are considered larger than "countably many points". Moreover, this could violate (1).
>
> 3) When $A$ is finite the Lebesgue/Khinchine integral does not give an average that takes the sum of the output of the finite points divided by the number of finite points. Instead, the average is zero. This violates (1).
>
> 4) When $A$ is countably dense, the Lebesgue integral does not give an average that matches the definition in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655102/coming-up-with-a-rigorous-definition-for-a-riemman-like-sum-which-is-easier-to-c). Once again the average is zero and violates (1).

Following from [@WillieWong's extended comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359457/87856), he [defines an integral](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359489/87856) which gives $f$ an average that matches my sum when $A$ is countable. Here is WillieWong's definition in Latex:

### @WillieWong's Definition

Here is @WillieWong's attempt to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655102/coming-up-with-a-rigorous-definition-for-a-riemman-like-sum-which-is-easier-to-c):

> First we construct a sequence of bounded functions $g_\sigma$ as
>   follows: start with your $A$. consider the set $A_\sigma = \cup_{x\in
>  A} (x - \sigma, x+\sigma)$. This is a union of of open intervals and
>   hence is an open set. As long as $A$ is non-empty this set is
>   non-empty, and hence has positive Lebesgue measure.
>
> Consider only $\sigma < 1/2$. Let $\chi_\sigma$ be the indicator
>   function of $A_\sigma$. Define $g_{\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{|A_\sigma|}
>  \int_{-1/2}^x \chi_\sigma(y) ~dy $.
>
> Here $|A_\sigma|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $A_\sigma$.
>
> Notice that $g_\sigma$ is normalized so that it takes value between
>   $0$ and $1$. (It is bounded.)
>
> And $g_\sigma$ is continuous. The question is whether there is, and
>   what is, the limit $\lim_{\sigma\to 0} g_{\sigma}$.
>
> When $|A| > 0$, then the family $g_\sigma$ is equicontinuous, and it
>   is not too hard to see that $g$ is formed as $\frac{1}{|A|}
>  \int_{-1/2}^x \chi(y) ~dy $ and here $\chi(y)$ is the indicator
>   function of $A$.
>
> The main question is what happens when $|A| = 0$. The conjecture is
>   that when $A$ has measure zero, but has a non-trivial perfect kernel,
>   then the limiting $g$ is a continuous function (like the Cantor
>   function). And when $A$ is scattered, the limiting $g$ is a step
>   function. In either case, the integral you are looking for should be
>   the Stieltjes integral with weight function $g$.

---

## Big Question

This definition only matches my sum when $A$ is countable. ***How do we extend @WillieWong's definition (above) to give an average that matches the results of my sum (below) for any $f$ and $A$.***

---

## My Sum

Don't worry about what drove me to define my sum the way it is. Focus on the main question.

Consider $S\subseteq A$ and $\lambda$ as the lebesgue measure,

$$M(S)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\lambda(S)}{\lambda(A)} & \lambda(A) >  0\\
0 & S \ \text{is countable and} \ A \ \text{is uncountable but} \ \lambda(A) = 0\\
1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The properties of $M(S)$ are such:

(1) $M(\emptyset)=\text{undefined}$

(2) $M(A)=1$

(3) When $\lambda(A) > 0$,

If $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are lebesgue measurable and disjoint, and $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=A$, then $M\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}M(A_i)= M(A_1)+...=1$.

From this we state when $\lambda(A)>0$, $M$ is countably additive.

(4) When $\lambda(A)=0$,

$M(A)$ is not countably additive. Instead we split $A$ into a union of countable $A_i$ (which we denote as $A_c$) and a union of uncountable $A_i$ (which we denote as $A_u$). If $M(A_c)=0$, then $M(A_u)=1$, because $M(A_c) + M(A_u) = M(A) = 1$. If $M(A_c)=1$, then $M(A_u)=0$ for the same reason. (I believe the additivity to be true).

Then we create upper and lower sums:

> Given $S \subseteq [0,1]$, and let $P$ be a partition of $[0,1]$ (note: a partition is a finite set of sub-intervals $X$ with disjoint interiors), you can define $P'(S) = \{ X\in P: X\cap S \neq \emptyset\}$. And you can define $n' = |P'(S)|$ (the number of sub-intervals in $P'$ which contain at least one element of $s$). Note each disjoint sub-interval $X$ has the same length.

Calculate/define the following:

$$\tilde{L}_{f,P} = \frac{1}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(S)} \bigg(\inf_{t \in X}f(t) \bigg)$$

$$\tilde{U}_{f,P} = \frac{1}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(S)} \bigg(\sup_{t \in X}f(t) \bigg)$$

Define the limits under refinements of $P$ like so:
$$\tilde{L}_f = \lim_{\|P\| \to 0}(L_{f,P})$$
$$\tilde{U}_f = \lim_{\|P\| \to 0}(U_{f,P})$$

Where $\|P\|=\sup_{X\in P}\|X\|$.
We would want these lower and upper kinda-averages limits to converge to the same value.

Note this still not completely rigorous and successful [@WillieWong's extended comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/359457/87856) and [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107629/new-discovery-riemman-like-sum).

We combine $M(S)$ and the upper and lower sums to create the fully definition of my sum. Note the upper and lower sums were created to determine when the average is defined and when it's undefined. Now, we make real definitions.

We define the full "lower average" as:

$$L_{f,P} = \frac{M(A)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A)} (\inf_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

and the full "upper average" as:

$$U_{f,P} = \frac{M(A)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A)} (\sup_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

If these lower and upper averages limits converge to the same value (id est: are equal), we are given "my complete definition of average" of $f$ for any $A$. If they do not converge, then the average is undefined. Notice I define "upper" and "lower" averages to show when an average can not exist.

---

### Example With General Piece-wise Function

Consider a general piece-wise function, $f(x)=f_i(x)$, when $x\in A_i$ such that $f_i:A_i\to[a,b]$ and $A_1,...,A_m$ are non-overlapping subsets of $A$.

When $\lambda(A)> 0$, the lower average of $f$ is

$$L_{f,P} = \frac{M(A_1)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_1)} (\inf_{t \in X}f(t) )+...+\frac{M(A_m)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_m)} (\inf_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

and the upper average of $f$ is

$$U_{f,P} = \frac{M(A_1)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_1)} (\sup_{t \in X}f(t) )+...+\frac{M(A_m)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_m)} (\sup_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

If the limit of the upper and lower average converge we have a defined average. If not the average is undefined. This is why I create upper and lower sums. I want cases where we can't have an average.

Lastly, if $\lambda(A)=0$, countable $A_i$ are combined into $A_c$ and uncountable $A_i$ are combined into $A_u$, then using property $(3)$ of $M(A)$, the lower average of $f$ is

$$L_{f,P} = \frac{M(A_c)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_c)} (\inf_{t \in X}f(t) )+\frac{M(A_u)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_u)} (\inf_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

and the upper average of $f$ is

$$U_{f,P} = \frac{M(A_c)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_c)} (\sup_{t \in X}f(t) )+\frac{M(A_u)}{n^{\prime}} \sum_{X \in P^{\prime}(A_u)} (\sup_{t \in X}f(t) )$$

Comment: This is supposed to be modelled on the Darboux sum and N is really the count of parts in a given partition?

Comment: @user173897 Pretty much. However, if there's infinite points in parts of a partition, then the length of those parts must approach zero. Otherwise for a function defined on all of $[a,b]$ we can adjust the length of the parts to equal any average in $P$'s range.

Comment: "I made my final edit. This should summarize everything I am looking for. – Arbuja Apr 5 at 19:43" And you have made 24 edits since making your final edit.

Comment: By the way, the first-year-calculus definition of the average value of $P$ on the set $A$ would be the integral of $P$ over the set $A$, divided by the measure of $A$. What are you looking for in an average that that definition doesn't have?

Comment: @GerryMyerson People on Reddit keep telling me my definitions aren’t clear so I have to keep editing.

Comment: @GerryMyerson We have to be specific. What measure? What integral?

Comment: How about Lebesgue measure & Lebesgue integral? If you have to keep editing, that's a clear signal that you weren't ready to post the question when you did. So, this question is being discussed on Reddit? You should give a link, so there's good communication & no duplication of effort.

Comment: To be completely honest this is very unclear. I'm not trying to be harsh but I'm not convinced even you know enough about your problem to phrase it precisely. Let's start with a simpler question that you can introduce at the start: what properties of the Lebesgue / Khinchine integral do you want that are not satisfied by those? Be as explicit as possible with specific functions that don't work.

Comment: here is link to concurrent reddit discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/fxvhod/how_clear_is_my_definition_of_average_could_we/

Comment: @Aaron I made edits to my post

Comment: @GerryMyerson Your right, but perhaps once this is clear I can post it onto math stack overflow.

Comment: @ziggurism Thank You! How clear is my post?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't find it very understandable.

Comment: @ziggurism How come? Can you please explain?

Comment: Probably should've waited until your post was understandable _before_ you gave it a bounty. You're going to spend the entire bounty period rewriting and rerewriting. Or maybe give the bounty to someone who can rewrite it in a legible way

Comment: @ziggurism Understand but how come my post is still unclear? Please explain?

Comment: Too many undefined symbols, symbols that are defined but not used, and unmotivated expressions and statements. Also, are you summing to uncountable cardinalities?

Comment: @ziggurism Be specific. Which symbol are defined but not used which expressions are unmotivated. If read closely you'll notice I defined everything.

Comment: @ziggurism Then how will I get an answer? I'm tired of people not being specific. WHAT IS UNCLEAR!!!

Comment: @ziggurism I did read it. I understand everything. Now please explain.

Comment: It seems like you want an operator like an expectation, that behaves one way for sets with strictly positive Lebesgue measure, and another way for sets that are finite or countable?  So, $P \in \mathcal{P}$ is a space of functions on some subset $A$ of $[a,b]$, and you want something like an integral $I: \mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that distinguishes between when $A$ is a set of measure zero versus a set of strictly positive measure?

Comment: @Renard Exactly! Do you understand precisely how I want them to be distinguished?

Comment: I think a problem is, what limits do you want to preserve or properties of the standard integral matter to you? The thing you are building will not be continuous for something like a limit of $[c-1/n,c+1/n]$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, $c\in (a,b)$. Sets that limit to sets of measure zero will behave in non standard ways.

Comment: @Renard I’m not sure, if my sum is additive then the integral should be additive. If the sum can isolate multiplied constants than the integral can be multiplicative. If a function is greater than another function than the integral of that function is greater than the integral of the other function.

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [How do we create a better definition (for my definition of average) which is easier to compute and gives exact values?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/358474)

Comment: @AllUsers If re-edited my post. If any of you have questions be sure to go to this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107629/new-discovery-riemman-like-sum)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Apologies I didn’t realize all I had to do was capitalize. I am extremely careless.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a partial answer for you. It does not exactly do what you are looking for, but I hope you will at least find it interesting. But in brief, you might want to think about the Hausdorff measure.

First, consider a related problem to the one you have been thinking about. We have some low-dimensional, bounded surface $S$ contained inside $\mathbb{R}^N$. We have a function $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. What is the "average" value of this function? If we integrate using the N-dimensional integral in $\mathbb{R}^N$, its "average" will just be zero, for the reason that any surface which is (N-1)-dimensional or lower inside $\mathbb{R}^N$ has N-dimensional Lebesgue measure (a.k.a. "volume") zero.

But! You might say. We don't care about the volume of $S$ inside the ambient space; we just care about its "volume"/"area" according to its own, intrinsic dimension. In other words, what we actually want is: a function that detects the dimensionality of as subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^N$, applies some appropriate lower-dimensional integral to $S$, and *then* we compute the average of $f$ on $S$ according to said measure.

In particular, consider a 2d surface embedded in 3d space. If we try and compute the (3d) volume of the 2d surface, it will be zero (according to the 3d Lebesgue measure); if we try to compute the "length" according to 1d Lebesgue measure, well, since it's a surface, we can fit uncountably many lines of finite length in the surface, so it should have "infinite length". But it may well have nonzero, non-infinite, surface area.

A technically fancy formalization of this idea is Hausdorff dimension/Hausdorff measure. But the idea is that we can detect the intrinsic dimension of a subset of a space by ranging through lower-dimensional measures, and looking for a critical value at which the measures switch from infinite down to zero. (In fact, Hausdorff dimension works for non-integer dimension, which is remarkable!) I encourage you to read the Wikipedia page for Hausdorff dimension/measure; unfortunately it's a technically tough construction but I think you can get it with effort.

How does this apply to your situation? Well, a countable set has Hausdorff dimension *zero*, and the zero-dimensional Hausdorff measure is just summation. So in particular, you can have a function defined as follows: let $A \subset [0,1]$. Let $d$ equal the Hausdorff dimension of $A$, let $\mathcal{H}^d(A)$ denote the Hausdorff measure of $A$ in dimension $d$. *If* $0<\mathcal{H}^d(A)<\infty$, then we can define the average $$\frac{1}{\mathcal{H}^d(A)} \int_A f(x) d\mathcal{H}^d(x).$$

In particular, for *finite* sets $A$ this gives the uniform average of $f$ on $A$, and for sets $A$ of positive Lebesgue measure it gives the average in the Lebesgue sense. For exotic sets which have Hausdorff dimension strictly between zero and one, it will do some weird thing that is somewhat hard (for me at least) to intuitively understand.

For countable sets we are in a sticky situation, because they have Hausdorff dimension 0 but 0-dimensional Hausdorff measure $+\infty$. Nonetheless, the idea of trying to "detect the dimension" of a set with Lebesgue measure zero is how one might think about this from a geometric measure theory perspective.

Comment: I need your help clarifying my post. No one wants to answer because it is so unclear. What do you understand?

Comment: I will be honest, I just remembered your problem from one of your previous questions and realized that Hausdorff measure might be closer to what you want. I did not read this question carefully.

Comment: If you have time is it possible to read over it.

Comment: I made more edits. What’s clear from last time?

Comment: I re-changed my post. If you have any questions we can chat [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107629/new-discovery-riemman-like-sum)

Comment: I think your writing has improved a lot. Unfortunately I don't have any further suggestions that I can think of right now.